# Ошибка отсутствия базы данных

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Помогите найти ошибку в коде. Вот я вчера написал код...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string host, database, user, password;
        public static string strProvider;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите хост");
            host = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя БД");
            database = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя пользователя");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите пороль");
            password = Console.ReadLine();

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider );
            MySqlCommand cmp = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmp.CommandText = "SELECT news FROM admin WHERE id=3";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            MySqlDataReader Reader = cmp.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Reader["title"].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске проги она должна мне выдать новость с 3-м id... но проходит ошибка, типа такой БД не существует...

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в том, что Вы инициализируете поля `host, database, user, password` из того, что ввёл пользователь, уже после того, как сформировали из них строку подключения.

Ещё одна ошибка в том, что `MySqlConnection` и `MySqlDataReader` нужно закрывать после использования. Возьмите их в блоки `using`:

```
using (MySqlDataReader Reader = cmp.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Reader["title"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибки нету, но появилась следующая "Table 'admin.admin' doesn't exist "

Answer (score 1):

трудно ответить без визуализации исходных параметров подключения...
есть подозрение, что у вас база называется admin. а таблица, в которой ищем тоже admin?
база как правило содержит несколько таблиц. проверьте эту версию.

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i408/1112/a3/1e3128e91f80.png

http://s017.radikal.ru/i426/1112/3a/bf04e6031496.png

Вот что у меня.

Comment: Понятно. там же есть ответ. во второй картинке. 
select * from NEWS
(специально выделил). 
т.е. база у вас Admin, а таблица News. из нее и выбирайте новости с нужным id

Comment: А можно полный SQL запрос? Просто я его вообще не учил и не знаю...

Comment: это немножко выходит за рамки топика...
select ПОЛЕ from ТАБЛИЦА where УСЛОВИЕ
вместо русских слов подставляете нужные идентификаторы. пока это все....

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.